# convert string to unique integer form

Tags: r, string, integer, transform

I have a vector of strings, it is in my case that strings are logical rules.
There are a lot of such rules, but I showed only three for clarity.

```
rules <- c("X[,1]>0.5 & X[,2]<1" , "X[,3]>0.2" , "X[,3]>0.3")
```

I would like to convert the rules to integer form, something like that

```
rules <- c("X[,1]>0.5 & X[,2]<1" , "X[,3]>0.2" , "X[,3]>0.3")
int <- rbind(c(0,0,2,5,0,1,0,0,1,0),c(1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

.

```
cbind.data.frame(rules,int)
                rules 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 X[,1]>0.5 & X[,2]<1 0 0 2 5 0 1 0 0 1  0
2           X[,3]>0.2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
3           X[,3]>0.3 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
```

There are three conditions

1. all `int` vectors  must be the same length
2. If the rule(string) is similar to another string, then the `int`vectors should be similar too. This is necessary in order to be able to calculate the distance between strings  or  `int`vectors.
   [image]
3. the ability to convert string to int form, as well as back int form to string

Is such a conversion possible?

Comment: Is there an `X` object on which these rules (that look like R expressions) are evaluated? I don't understand otherwise how we're supposed to know how to generate those sequences of numbers.

Comment: Ok, Imagine that the "rules" are just an ordinary vector  :  rules <- c("AAA" , "B6" , "B7")

Comment: Sure ... but I *still* don't understand how to go from `"AAA"` to `c(0,0,2,5,0,1,0,0,1,0)`. It seems arbitrary. What is the relationship between a string and your columns named `"1"` through `"10"`?

Comment: I thought it might be the case that `X[,1]` (in your `rules`) might imply the first column in a matrix or frame-like object, but your comment suggests otherwise. I also thought it might be a derivation of character-position within the string, but the number of chars in each does not lend to that.

Comment: The problem is that I also don't know how to get to this, I thought there was a way to do it ...
For example, as in this package https://fnoorian.github.io/gramEvol/inst/doc/ge-intro.html
Any expression can be created and each expression has its own unique genotype http://prntscr.com/1qqfwm2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the rules are similar to the ones you showed, one way to do would be to generate a standard `X` matrix, parse each of the rules and apply them to X.  That will generate vectors of TRUE and FALSE (which are easily converted to 1 and 0) with length `nrow(X)`.

For example,

```r
set.seed(123)
X <- matrix(runif(3000, 0, 2), nrow = 1000)
rules <- c("X[,1]>0.5 & X[,2]<1" , "X[,3]>0.2" , "X[,3]>0.3")
int <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(rules), ncol = nrow(X))
for (i in seq_along(rules)) 
  int[i,] <- as.numeric(eval(parse(text = rules[i])))
rownames(int) <- rules

dist <- matrix(NA, length(rules), length(rules),
               dimnames = list(rules, rules))
for (i in seq_along(rules)) 
  for (j in seq_along(rules)) 
    dist[i, j] <- sqrt(sum((int[i,] - int[j,])^2))

dist
#>                     X[,1]>0.5 & X[,2]<1 X[,3]>0.2 X[,3]>0.3
#> X[,1]>0.5 & X[,2]<1             0.00000  24.67793  24.28992
#> X[,3]>0.2                      24.67793   0.00000   7.28011
#> X[,3]>0.3                      24.28992   7.28011   0.00000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: You are doing a distance matrix, but it doesn't work for me, I have too big "rules" vector, I would like to get unique IDs for each "rules"

Comment: You need to be more specific about what is wrong.  How big is the real `rules` vector?

Comment: tens of millions elements in the "rules" vector, I will also need to count it many times

Comment: Why not just stop my calculation after the generation of `int`, or even write a function to compute a single `int` row, and not save any of them?